# What is the best practice when reviewing a post pointing asking for changes to a website that is in production?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, specific-question

I recently reviewed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54949645/vertically-center-product-images-in-shopify-debut-theme) as spam. I did this because the question that they were asking had already been answered before (granted it was offsite, and I could link to it) and they appeared to only be posting a vague question for people to click through to their website.

Leaving it on hold still allows their link to be clicked by people and their website to be viewed. Thus, I believe it would be better to close the current question to prevent their link from being clicked and force them to repost with a valid MCV example.

The kernel of my question is when it is appropriate to link to a website for purposes of examples and when it is not. If products are actively being sold on a website does that constitute spam?

Comment: It isn't spam unless its spam, and its always inappropriate.

Comment: @KevinB would the appropriate action for them to take be screenshotting rather than linking directly to the website?

Comment: No, the appropriate action would be them creating an MCVE. If they can't recreate the problem in a smaller test case, they aren't ready to ask a question.

Comment: @KevinB I am fairly sure they are using a third party website designer so they aren't actually sure of the code that is causing it.

Comment: I mean, that's not really our problem.

Comment: @KevinB so you are saying it is 100% spam? The flag I raised was disputed.

Comment: No, not at all. it's simply a bad question. It's a question that should be asked of the builders of said website designer. It's kinda like someone asking on stackoveflow about an error they're getting in the console when they open youtube.

Comment: If you start seeing dozens of questions all linking to the same website, and they're all bad questions, and none of the questions from the users are ever not including that link, then you could make a good argument for spam.  But one (bad) question linking a website isn't spam, it's just a bad question.

Comment: If this question *was* spam, it'd be a rather poor attempt at spam considering the url isn't even a clickable link.

Comment: @KevinB Sometimes that's an attempt to subvert spam detection systems.  (Although I don't think this is spam.  Just saying that's not a good heuristic for "not spam").

Comment: Post got deleted. I'm not sure it's a bad question and the close reason is no longer appropriate so I punched re-open. It's still deleted.

Answer (score 15):

Spam has a different *texture* to it, if you will.

We get a surprising amount of questions from users who want us to help them with their website, who also provide a link to their website.  In and of itself, **that is not spam**; they are not *necessarily* advertising a link and attempting to promote their product; they may be looking for help.

(Spoiler alert:  that's not how Stack Overflow works.  You aren't going to get help if you post a link to your website and ask us to "do all the things".)

Spam looks like a blatant and overt attempt to try and sell someone on their product.  This manifests itself in the form of what looks (and feels) like dodgy advertisements about a product completely unrelated to anything we do here at Stack Overflow.

My belief is to give the person the benefit of the doubt here and not believe that this is spam.  It's a ***really*** bad question and it should be/remain closed as "Too Broad", but there's no spammy nature to it.

Comment: All true. In these cases, I give both sides the benefit of the doubt by disputing the flag. I would never outright decline a spam flag on an abysmally low-quality question that contained little more than a link to an external site. At the same time, it’s probably just a really confused asker, so no need to handle it as spam. Closing as too broad or lacking an MCVE is sufficient.